# continuity of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,2]\rightarrow [0,2],$ given by
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x, & \text{ if } x\in [0,1),\\
3 - x, & \text{ if } x\in [1,2].
\end{cases}
$$
Is $f$ a continuous function ?

Comment: Is $f$ continuous at $1$?

Comment: You have a jump discontinuity at x=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $I\ni 1$ is an open interval, is $f^{-1}(I)$ open?

Comment: could you give me some more details ?

Comment: @b.taylor $f$ is continuous means that the preimage of *every single* open set is open. Find an open set whose preimage is *not* open.

Answer (score 4):

hint:
$$\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)\neq\lim_{x\to 1^+}f(x)$$